# ggplot colour bar with 2 scales (top and bottom)

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization, tidyverse

I am trying to make a ggplot2 with a colour bar with two scales  (or two sets of labels) on both sides of the colour bar (for example having both a cm and inches scale on the left and right side of colour guide bar or having Celsius AND Fahrenheit). Is something like that possible in ggplot2?  See picture for what I am looking for (ideally, in this small example I would have the numbers 1:5 at the bottom of the bar and the letters a:e on the top of the bar). Could I make two legends and just overlay them somehow? also having a title on the top and bottom would be helpful

```
df <- tibble(A = letters[1:5], B = 1:5)
  
ggplot(df, aes(x = A, y = B, fill = B)) +
  geom_col() +
  scale_fill_gradient(high = "blue",  low = "red",
                      labels = letters[1:5],
                       guide = guide_colorbar(
                         direction = "horizontal",
                         title.position = 'top',
                         title.hjust = 0.5,
                         label.hjust = 0.5,
                         legend.location = "bottom",
                         label.position = "top")
                      ) +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom")
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice question. Unfortunately not at a console right now, and those online code running sites are not versatile eonough for me to provide a solution. Check https://github.com/clauswilke/multiscales which might help. Another option might be `ggnewscale` package. Or create both gradient legends as separate plots and stitch them together with the `patchwork` package

Comment: Rather a workaround than a real solution, but might be a (small) step in the direction you want to achieve: ```labels = paste0(letters[1:5], "\n", 1:5),```

Comment: Thank you both. Wolfgang, that is indeed a solution to the current example, but would not work for the actual viz I need to make. Tjebo, I have looked around those 3 packages, but not find a solution (The best solution so far being adding two of the same fill bars with `ggnewscale` with different labels, but that is still not a real solution). I will leave this question open for now.